# Oracle--Error(Refereence to object_id)

Tags: oracle

`SELECT object_id from dbname.tablename`

This query has to be executed against oracle 11g.I get errors when i execute this.

I do a migration from sybase to oracle and in oracle this query fails.
What could be the problem. Please suggest a solution

Comment: -1 for not providing details about the error or what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

**"What could be the problem."**

All sorts of things. Since you failed to state what errors you're getting, we can only guess, e.g.:

- Table not found
- No SELECT privilege on table
- `dbname` not a valid schema
- `object_id` not a column in the table
- Not connected to a running oracle instance
- Trying to run the statement in an environment that doesn't understand SQL

  etc, etc, ...

If all you want is to check that the table exists, you could do this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dba_tables WHERE owner = 'DBNAME' AND table_name = 'TABLENAME';
```

If you want to check that you can query the table, you could do this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM schemaname.tablename WHERE 1=0;
```

If you want to check if the table has any rows, you could do this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM schemaname.tablename WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Comment: based on a later answer it appears the OP wants to know if the table exists.  But I think that your first query above, which should answer this question, would throw a NO_DATA_FOUND exception (at least in PL/SQL) if the table didn't exist.  If the "SELECT 1" is changed to a "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TABLE_COUNT" the first query will always return a row with TABLE_COUNT set appropriately.

Comment: @Bob - yep that's right. Personally I prefer NO_DATA_FOUND but that's just because I love exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

What you will do with the result. If you only want a unique id for a row, yo can user `SELECT ROWID FROM dbname.tablename`!

Comment: I am using this query in oracle to check whether a table exists or not.